# How to update new adapters in Prebid server?

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

When I try to send a request with a taboola adapter, I get a response: "Invalid request: request.imp[0].ext contains unknown bidder: taboola. Did you forget an alias in request.ext.prebid.aliases?"
I checked the adapters folder and I didn't see Taboola there.
How to update new adapters to the project?

I attach the request json for send a request: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQqm2.png)